# Unable to edit .bashrc with anything

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code

I'm using bash (WSL) and VsCode to edit .bashrc, but I keep getting an error.

```
"C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" --file-write "c:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Code\code-elevated-VCl4X1Tf" "\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\USER\.bashrc" Error using --file-write: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\USER\.bashrc'
```

I'm not even able to edit .bashrc with nano from within bash, so I changed permissions on the file so I could read write and execute it, but nothing changed.

What should I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What error do you get when you edit via `nano ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Sorry, I got caught up in other stuff. When using nano to edit the file, it had red text that said "[ File '.bashrc' is unwritable ]". I'm not sure why. I cant use anything to edit it even after changing permissions of the file.